# What is the import type in springboot mvc mock kotlin, for the status and the isOK

Tags: spring, kotlin, model-view-controller, status, mockk

In spring mvc mock kotlin, what is the import class for the status and the isok

thankyou

```
import ???
@Test
    fun findUser() {
        mockMvc.get("/users?id=99")
            .andExpect {
                status { isOk }
            }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers

@Test
fun findUser() {
  mockMvc.get("/users?id=99")
      .andExpect {
          status { isOk() }
      }
}
```